# Why is the uncle missing?

Tags: twin-peaks

In the *Twin Peaks* movie [*Fire Walk With Me*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105665/), there's a scene in which [two FBI agents receive some information about their case encoded in a short dance by a woman named Lil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dNwFVk68PI).

The FBI agent who provides the information (by presenting the dancer) also says (from the [script](http://www.lynchnet.com/fwwm/fwwmscript.html)):

> SHE'S MY MOTHER'S SISTER'S GIRL.

In the following scene, the FBI agents analyze and decode the information seen in the dance. The analysis of the above remark goes as follows:

> DESMOND (continued)
>
> Cole said Lil was "his mother's sister's girl".  What is missing in that sentence? The Uncle.
>
> STANLEY
>
> Oh, the uncle is missing.
>
> DESMOND
>
> Not Cole's Uncle but probably the sheriff's uncle in federal prison.

My question is: **Based upon the statement that Lil is "[someone's] mother's sister's girl", how would one come to the conclusion that the uncle is missing (or that anyone is missing at all)?**

I have found [a reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/twinpeaks/comments/2tkmvm/shes_my_mothers_sisters_girl/) about this question, but I fail to understand the explanation proposed there:

- First, the fact that some sheriff's uncle is in federal prison must be irrelevant. After all, if you already have that bit of information, no additional knowledge is conveyed by the "mother's sister's girl" statement.
- Second, of course "my mother's sister's girl" is a longer form of saying "my cousin", but it's also a more precise form, so it doesn't actually seem unusual to use this longer form.
- Third, while mother, sister, and daughter ("girl") happen to be female, that may just be what the family relationship between them is. It's not like you could deliberately choose between "my mother's sister's girl" and "my mother's brother's girl" to refer to the same person. Hence, it escapes me how mother, sister, and daughter all being female can carry any encoded meaning.

To conclude, *if* we assume anyone is missing in the statement (which I still see no reason for), "your own father" appears to be just as good an answer as "the uncle".